# Сборка Scala проекта. Gradle или sbt?

Tags: gradle, build, scala

Прошу поделиться опытом тех, кто имеет опыт разработки и сопровождения больших проектов на Scala.

Какие особенности и отличия между сборкой с помощью Gradle c плагином scala и sbt?

Я попробовал на тестовых проектах оба инструмента, зависимости резолвят оба, собирают jar-ы тоже, т.е. простые таски выполняются примерно одинаково.

Интересно послушать сложности/тонкие моменты или наоборот плюсы и минусы каждого инструмента, внять опыт тех, кто основательно использовал оба инструмента.

Comment: Отличия в каком плане? В sbt билд и таски можно писать на scala, а в gradle на groovy. Если scala основной язык разработки, то логичнее наверное использовать sbt.

Answer (score 1):

Sbt и Gradle обладают сопоставимой функциональностью. Лично я предпочитаю использовать Gradle, в виду наличия удобного понятного dsl, понятной и удобной документации, а так же наличия бОльшего сообщества чем для sbt. В Gradle существует одна небольшая проблема при работе со scala-проектами, а именно неудачно отображается scala console. Для sbt такой проблемы не существует.
Однако, чем больше становится размер проекта тем сложнее поддерживать его с sbt. Использование `build.sbt` становится затруднительным, а потом невозможным. Код сборки приходится писать уже на scala, используя sbt как библиотеку. Sbt обладает достаточно странным API и множеством странно перегруженных операторов, что затрудняет чтение и поддержку. Однако, является стандартом де-факто в мире scala. По своей пратике скажу что большая часть scala проектов вообще использует для сборки Maven, Gradle на втором месте, и уже потом идет sbt.

Так же стоит отметить универсальнгость Gradle что делает его более удобным при наличии других языков (не только Java и Scala)